# (AzureAD - Powershell) How to get the permissions assigned for a user/groupe?

Tags: azure

Why such a basic thing is not referenced?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Permissions for what?

Comment: For everything. I just want to *see* the permissions for one group or one user. Im not even looking for display a specific permission. Having a command who display anything ressemble to a permission from AzureAD will be a present from the gods.

Comment: So are you looking which apps the user has been assigned or what resources they can edit/read in Azure? Or something else?

Comment: No no. Just display the permissions the user have. Like this : "Group.ReadWrite.All" this is a permission.
Example, I run a command called 'Get-AzureADPerm' and voilà, I get all the permissions possible. But this thing dosent exists. You can add.  You can delete. But you may never see.

Comment: So you want to know if a user can for example, create groups?

Comment: No. These thing can be finded with logic. But to have the logic, I have to get the proof the user can. I'm not going to create a user and say "oh, he can, so he must have the permission to do so !" thats the better way to screw up everthing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to [**get oAuth2PermissionGrant object of a user**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduseroauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0).

You can use this powershell cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADUserOAuth2PermissionGrant
   -ObjectId <String>
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Example:**

```
$user = get-azureaduser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'wayne@contoso.com'"

Get-AzureADUserOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId $user.ObjectId
```

Here is my test and result:
[image]

NOTE:
 This command is for the oAuth2 Pemission Grant  of a user, Objects are actually Azure AD applications which the account grant his permissions to .

Comment: Thats great, because Its exaclty what im looking for. But like everything else, the fun MUST continue, so, the destiny decides that wonderful command will not work for me :)

Comment: Hi,@Naeso .I'm not very clear about your comment. Why this command doesn't work for you?

Comment: it does nothing.